# What does grouping in extended regular expressions mean?

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

I read that grouping treats an expression as a single unit. What does that mean?

Furthermore, what does `grep "\(grouping\)" file.txt` or `grep -E "(grouping)" file.txt` do? I also read that expressions are grouped with parenthesis. Again, what is grouping expressions?

When I run the command, it highlights `grouping` in the file. How is `grep "\(grouping\)"` different from `grep grouping`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, it causes whatever is inside the parentheses to be treated as a single atom. This is useful if you want to apply a quantifier for example. Compare:

```
$ printf 'groupinggrouping' | grep -Eo "grouping*"
groupingg
```

(where `*` is only applied to the `g`) with

```
$ printf 'groupinggrouping' | grep -Eo "(grouping)*"
groupinggrouping
```

where `*` is applied to the whole subpattern `grouping`.

In most (all?) regex dialects, `(grouping)` also *captures* the matched text into an indexed *capture group*, allowing it to subsequently be *backreferenced*. That doesn't have too many applications in `grep` - the most obvious one is for detecting repeated elements ex.

```
$ printf 'ba\nbb\nbc\n' | grep '\(.\)\1'
bb
```

matches any single character that is followed by the same character. In the context of pattern substitution (in `sed` for example, rather than `grep`), the captured group may also be referenced in the replacement text.

There are other variants in more expressive dialects - such as Perl's `(?:grouping)` **non**-capturing groups.

For further information see for example

- [Use Parentheses for Grouping and Capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)